# Cannot get inline style to work in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to react and still noobish on html/css/javascript. I am trying to simply have my RandomNumberButton sit on the same line as my h2 tagged text. I believe the answer is just stick both items in a div tag, and set the css display property to inline. I tried wrapping it in a div tag with that style but with no luck. Let me know what I can do.

Here is the render function from my App.jsx

```
render: function () {
return (
  <div>
    <h2> Hello, {this.state.name}! </h2>
    <MyForm />
    <div style={{"display": "inline"}}> <RandomNumberButton /> <h2>Random Number: {this.state.randomNumber}</h2></div>
  </div>
);
```

}

and my RandomNumberButton.jsx render function

```
render: function () {
  return (
      <button onClick={this._generateRandomNumber}>Generate a random number</button>
  );
}
```

*I updated the code to not be litered with possibly extraneous div tags trying to make that h2 tag display inline with the RandomNumberButton element*

Comment: is it neccessary to put it intro curly brackets!? what if you use <div style="display: inline;">

Comment: If I do not add the curly brackets I get the error: ReactifyError: /home/kashtand/node-react-flux/src/App.jsx: Parse Error: Line 54: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text while parsing file: /home/kashtand/node-react-flux/src/App.jsx

Comment: are you able to determine if the style is in the compiled html using a web developer console?

Comment: Is the compiled html found in the elements section? I see the inline style property there on the div tags that I specified it on

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this piece of code doesnt work for you. Also you can implement it using an object. Example below and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/21416/):

```
var AppStyle = {
  divStyle : {
    display : 'inline'
  }
  // , here you can add lots of another styles for your component
}
```

and then in your component you can assign it to a *style*

```
render: function () {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Hello, {this.state.name}! </h2>
      <MyForm />
      <div style={AppStyle.divStyle}> // JS object
        <RandomNumberButton /> 
        <h2>Random Number: {this.state.randomNumber}</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
);
```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

wrap both key and value in quotes.

```
<div style={{"display": "inline"}}>
```

Comment: The key does not need to be in quotes.

Comment: Personally I wrap both in quotes, I see nothing wrong with the way he is using inline styles in React, I do it the same way all the time without issue, there has to be something else wrong.

Comment: I do not get any errors in my developer console or in my Gulp build. Is there any other code that could affect what is going on? I am stuck. If I remove the h2 tag it unsurprisingly stays inline.

Comment: I added the style={{"display": "inline"}} to my h2 tag and now it works. This is not very satisfying for me, it makes more sense to me to specify that style on my parent div tag... any ideas on why I had to put it on the h2 tag?

Comment: Weird,... really shouldn't make any difference, are you sure you are compiling well? Why don't you just use a class for this?

Comment: I am using a css class for the style, and it still has to be on the h2 tag. Does anybody know why it wouldn't work when the style is set just on the div?

Comment: what happens if you wrap it in another div? and have the inline style in the inner div, does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I use flexbox in a common index.css.

```css
.FlexBox {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
}

.FlexBoxJustAround {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.FlexBoxJustBetween {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.FlexBoxWrap {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.FlexJustify {
 -webkit-box-pack: justify;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.FlexBoxStretch {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 align-content: stretch;
}

.FlexItem {
 flex-grow: 1;
}

.HighZ {z-index: 200;}
```

```js
<div id='HalfStackButtonAreaSty' className="FlexBox" style={HalfStackButtonAreaSty}>
  <JButton btn={pasteSnipBtn} parentClickHandler={this.clickHandler} />
  <JButton btn={newSnipBtn} parentClickHandler={this.clickHandler} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a variable instead and see if that helps your code:

```
render: function () {
  return (
    var inline = {'display': 'inline'}
    <div>
      <h2>Hello, {this.state.name}!</h2>
      <MyForm />
      <div style={inline}>
        <RandomNumberButton />
        <h2>Random Number: {this.state.randomNumber}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It didn't compile at first, I moved the var outside of the render function, but there was no change